# How do I make the scale the same on these two graphs in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I make the scale the same on these two graphs in Google Sheets?

[image]

On the x axis is t/time, on the y axis is amplitude..

In the  x/y on the second graph/table, I made those x values to be 2* the ones in the first graph/table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two overlapping graphics, the second of which with a transparent background
[image: graph]

[test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WV_9HK-0ha-FTOR-q6obvBkFexCWkyYsemBFs0BoBuE/edit?usp=sharing)

Or just a single graph but changing the amp2 column
[image: chart]
[other test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tajpksfbH4u8ukWSNsDRZWH8OC0wA2Ub0wAVByZBLDY/edit?usp=sharing)